# Elasticsearch query not giving expected result

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7, elasticsearch-7

This is the doc I have in my index(there can be several too):

```
{
        "_index" : "meeting",
        "_type" : "meeting",
        "_id" : "27",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "createTime" : "2020-07-20T14:49:05.803",
          "createTimeInMs" : 1595234945803,
          "createdBy" : "sdf@sdfsd.com",
          "editTime" : "2020-07-20T14:49:05.803",
          "editTimeInMs" : 1595234945803,
          "editedBy" : "sfsf@sdfsdf.com",
          "versionId" : 1,
          "id" : "27",
          "projectId" : "62",
          "projectName" : "sdfsdf",
          "meetingName" : "meeting1",
          "agenda" : "string",
          "startDateString" : "2020-07-20T00:45:19.604",
          "userId" : 3,
          "memberList" : [
            3,
            4
          ],
          "status" : "ACTIVE",
          "timeZone" : "Asia/Dhaka",
          "startDate" : "2020-07-20T00:45:19.604",
          "endDate" : "2020-07-20T01:45:19.604",
          "dateInMS" : 1595227519000,
          "meetingPlace" : "string",
          "endDateString" : "2020-07-20T01:45:19.604"
        }
      }
```

***Logically, I am trying to build this condItion:***

```
if((projectId==62 && startDate>=inputFrom && startDate <=inputTo) && (status==ACTIVE ||status==POSTPONED))
```

My Query(from kibana):

```
GET /meeting/_search?pretty
{
  "query": 
  {
    "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "projectId" : {
            "value" : "62",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "terms" : {
          "status" : [
            "ACTIVE",
            "POSTPONED"
          ],
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "range" : {
          "startDate" : {
            "from" : "2020-07-19T23:45:19.604Z",
            "to" : "2020-07-20T00:49:19.604Z",
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
  }
}
```

I am comparing with range query for `startDate` field within mentioned range with other `must` fields above. But not getting any hit!
I want to retrieve documents which has `startDate` within the range of given `from` and `to` date.
Being quite inexperienced in this arena, don't know why not working! Please help how to fix this query to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use bool to combine multiple queries in this way. The must clause will work as logical AND, and will make sure all the conditions are matched.**

To return documents that contain terms within a provided range refer this ES official documentation on [Range Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#range-query-time-zone)

Since you have not provided any mapping for the data you have indexed, I have not specified any explicit mapping for the index.

The below search query will give you the expected result according to your condition specified in the question.

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "projectId": "62"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "startDate": {
              "gte": "2020-07-20T00:44:19.604",
              "lte": "2020-07-21T00:45:19.604"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "status.keyword": "ACTIVE"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "status.keyword": "POSTPONED"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Later I have followed this approach just without bool for should clause and serves my purposes!

Comment: @user404 okay :) Since u have not provided any answer of your own, (and this answer also solves your problem) so can u please accept this answer as it would help others also to resolve their issue if they got stuck in a similar type of issue :) And thank u for upvoting the answer :)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts ! And accepting as mine and yours are almost similar